# Does assembler run on OS X, iOS and android?

Tags: android, ios, macos, assembly

Does the assembler programming language run on OS X, iOS or Android?

If so, How would could I run a .asm file?

Comment: Each device has some CPU, which has particular instruction set, and for each of them (x86, x86-64, various ARM revisions and MIPS) there exist several assemblers. If you have some .asm file, it's very likely it doesn't target particular OS of these, as most of the people program in different languages. It would be major pain to write everything 6+ (!) times for Android (if you want to support all CPU targets), so it's much more efficient to use C++, then profile the code, and hand-optimize only parts where the compiler fails (and usually adjusting the C++ source is enough to fix it).

Comment: Note: Assembler is the program that converts assembly language code into binary (to make it simple). There is no assembler language nor a single assembly language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do provide assemblers on all 3 platforms, the only problem is that you must ensure that the existing .asm file fits into the hardware ISA (instruction set architecture) before you do that, but it's not so easy because OSX runns on the x86 ISA, iOS on ARM (there are many versions in the world), and Android support many different ISAs such as x86, ARM and MIPS.